# Is it possible to inherit an anim xml resource from another and overwrite attributes?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I have these two files in `res/anim` folder:

**my_anim.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <rotate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

**my_anim_faster.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <rotate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />
</set>
```

Both are the same animation, only the speed (`android:duration`) changes. Is there a way to make this code shorter? For instance, by `my_anim_faster` inheriting from `my_anim` and overwrite `android:duration` attribute or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little briefing: `XML` resource cannot be inherited. The `xml` approach gives you the ability to create easy and fast resources like drawables, animations and layouts, but there is no way to inherit them. Google added `fragments` that allows you to extend and reuse layout functionality in some way but this is not an inheritance. In drawable/animation resources you can reuse other resources but you cannot extend them. So if you want to reuse some logic try to design your resources such a way that you can reuse them in another ones.

Now to your case: No, there is no way to do this via `xml`. Using `xml` you can only **describe** your resource. You can change the duration using `java` code programmatically.

```
Animation myAnimation = ...;
...
myAnimation.setDuration(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I though that there was a way like `parent` attribute in `style`/`theme` resources. I'll do it by code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i'm aware you can't inherit other animations when creating an animation in xml like how you can "include" a layout when creating a layout.

Your best bet would to create the animation programmatically (in an AnimationUtils class for example) and when you call it supply the duration as an argument. e.g.

```
MyAnim myAnim = new MyAnim(1000);
```